# Bibliographystyles that link multiple Bibtex fields to an URL

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

The `bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}` elegantly does not display the URL itself but links the journal, volume, number, year to the URL:
[image]
`bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}` however is rather concise, it for example does not display the document title.
What other bibliographystyles are availabe that also perform the URL trick but are less concise?

N.B.1 It should work with Bibtex. Most publication venues have not yet adopted biblatex.
N.B.2 I am not looking for a way to edit a bibliographystyle to perform the URL trick, because I noticed that requires editing .bst files:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64695/120150
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127819/120150
[BibTeX code to create hyperlinks from either DOI or URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565638/120150)
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200180/120150
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84151/120150

Comment: If you intend to submit a paper for publication somewhere then they often mandate the use of a specific bibliography style, to create a uniform appearance and behavior of all published papers. For conferences the LaTeX output is generally used as-is, but for journals the LaTeX version is just for review and the paper will be re-typeset for the actual publication. So your request (while valid in itself) is not very likely to survive the publication process.

Comment: I know, it's meant for my thesis, which will consists of bundled papers.

Comment: But in that case you could use BibLaTeX I guess? First publish the papers using the requirements from the conferences/publishers, then change the bibliography formatting for your own thesis.

Comment: Yes, but that would require me to learn BibLateX and subsequently edit my code; I prefer to make effective use of what I already have.

Comment: Ok, but in that case you could still use the approach of editing a `.bst` file. Maybe a suitable bibliography style already exists, but if not it is probably good to keep such options open for answers here.